# addEventListener for element which was hidden on page load

Tags: javascript, css, font-awesome, visibility, addeventlistener

I have a one FAB button in my homepage, on clicking on that FAB button it shows up three more buttons. Those three buttons will be hidden when the page is loaded and I have done it using CSS selectors,

```
fab-main#fab-button + div{
  visibility: hidden;
}
fab-main#fab-button:hover + div{
  visibility: visible;
  animation: scale-in 0.5s;
}
```

I am trying to register the addEventListener for the FAB elements in my HTML. Please note that I am using the Custom Element

```
 class testSample extends HTMLElement {
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.addEventListener("click", () => {
                this.openPage();
            });
        }
}

window.onload = function () {
    window.customElements.define("fab-main", testSample);
}
```

And the HTML code is

```
  <fab-main class='fab fas fa-comment-dots' id="fab-button"></fab-main>

    <div class="home-expand">
        <div class="home-expand-item">
            <fab-main class='fab fas fa-comment-dots'></fab-main>
        </div>
        <div class="home-expand-item">
            <fab-main class='fab fas fa-comment-dots'></fab-main>
        </div>
        <div class="home-expand-item">
            <fab-main class='fab fas fa-comment-dots'></fab-main>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**My problem:**

Click event not working for the FAB buttons which is initially set to hidden. I am able to get the click event for the button which is visible but not for the other three buttons.

**NOTE:** I am trying to register the listeners in window.onload.

Comment: @MisterJojo, updated the code with HTML

Comment: Are you using some sort of templating engine? I've never heard of tab-main

Comment: Where are you executing the `addEventListener`? What is `this` in that context?

Comment: What does `this.openPage()` do? How does it know which button you clicked on?

Comment: If you run `this.addEventListener()` in the `window.onload` function, `this` will be `window`, so you're not adding the listener to the button.

Comment: Don't use curly quotes in HTML: `<div class=“home-expand“>`

Comment: @Barmar I am using custom elements. Please find the updated code. I think there is problem with curly quotes when I copy paste it.

Comment: @MisterJojo sorry about the confusion. Please find the updated question with Custom element code.

Comment: I can't see any reason why that code would make a distinction between visible and hidden elements.

Comment: Can you turn this into a [mcve]?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with custom elements, but I suspect you need to define them *before* the DOM is loaded. Otherwise, the elements are already created and the constructor won't be executed.

Comment: I take that back. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements) says **for the custom element to work, the script that registers it has to be loaded after the DOM is parsed.**

Comment: Revealing the hidden elements and clicking on them works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/t0p98amh/6/

Comment: @Barmar thank you. Guess setting visibility style from JS is making the buttons to work properly. Thanks a lot. I will make sure to post a working sample going forward.

Comment: How were you trying to click on them if they're not visible?

Comment: @Barmar, I am trying to show the other hidden elements when the fab-main is tapped and then the items will be visible.

Comment: Your CSS only makes them visible while you're hovering over fab-main. When you move the mouse to the other elements, you're not over fab-main any more, so they're hidden again and you can't tap on them.